# UI hangs when using threads C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am using multithreading to do some tasks but when I start the process, the UI hangs, I am using the same method in another solution and its working fine!

Here is a snippet. I tried to use HTMLagality as well, but I don't think this is the reason, this method uses the normal http web request

Using C#, VS 2015, .Net Framework 4.6.1

```
 var th = new Thread(() =>
            {
                if (LinksToGetEmailsListView.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    LinksToGetEmailsListView.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
                    {
                        foreach (ListViewItem link in LinksToGetEmailsListView.Items)
                        {       
                            #region Extracting Emails from Html Page
                            //instantiate with this pattern 

                            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(link.Text);
                            httpWebRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                            httpWebRequest.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0)";

                            httpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
                            httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

                            string file;
                            var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                            using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                            {
                                file = sr.ReadToEnd();
                            }


                            string[] result = GetEmailsFromWebContent(file);
                            foreach (string r in result)
                            {
                                XtraMessageBox.Show(r);
                            }
                            #endregion






                            //   string[] result = GetEmailsFromWebContent(iWeb.Load(link.Text).DocumentNode.OuterHtml);
                            link.Focused = true;
                           // foreach (string email in result)
                            //{
                 //               XtraMessageBox.Show(email);
                            //}

                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (ListViewItem link in LinksToGetEmailsListView.Items)
                    {

                        #region Extracting Emails from Html Page
                        //instantiate with this pattern 

                        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(link.Text);
                        httpWebRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                        httpWebRequest.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0)";

                        httpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
                        httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

                        string file;
                        var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                        using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                        {
                            file = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        }


                        string[] result = GetEmailsFromWebContent(file);
                        foreach (string r in result)
                        {
                            XtraMessageBox.Show(r);
                        }
                        #endregion
                    }

                }


            });
            th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            th.Start();
```

Comment: Be more specific - in which code path does it hang?

Comment: @Nick

in the http web request , its get request !

Comment: There is what we call `UI Thread` where all UI-related behaviors should be placed. On your sample code you are creating a new thread and you're trying to perform UI-related actions such as `XtraMessageBox.Show(r);`. Make sure that it runs on the UI thread instead. Try looking up on how to invoke to the UI thread.

Comment: I already removed XtraMessagebox from the thread and it didn't solve it !

Comment: This is way too much code to post. Try to be concise and only post the Code that actually gives you trouble. It makes the entire thing a lot easier for us to read and understand

Answer (score 3):

You're actually running all that code *on the UI thread*, which is why the UI is hanging. You start a secondary thread, but then you **immediately** do a `InvokeRequired` / `Invoke` check. Well; it *will* be required, because *you're on a secondary thread*. So... the first thing you do in your secondary thread is push the work right back to the UI thread.

You probably wanted to defer the `Invoke` until you're actually ready to update the UI, i.e. around the final `XtraMessageBox.Show` (and possibly the `foreach` around that). And importantly: *remove* it from earlier in the method.

Comment: when I removed the http web request the UI didn't hang up ! do you have any idea how I can fix that ! I already removed XtraMessage

Comment: @JamesRick like I said: get rid of the premature `InvokeRequired` / `Invoke`, so that you aren't doing the http on the UI thread; move the `Invoke` lower down, when you're *actually ready to update the UI*